# Asp.Net(C#) inline coding Eval if statement problem

Tags: asp.net, eval

<%# Eval("NAME").ToString() == "Edit" ? %>
    ' />

Error: Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ',

How to make please help me?

Thank you all;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/icoedit.png" CommandName="Edit" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("NAME").ToString() == "Edit") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

Comment: can u tick question as answered? Thanks

Comment: I just went to vote for this and found out that I've looked it up before and voted on it last year. Lol. Thanks again! Wish I could remember all the things I've ever looked up.

Answer (score 0):

The ? on the end looks like you are going for a ternary operator but you haven't finished it off.

Personally in this situation I like to use the visible property like:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/icoedit.png" 
CommandName="Edit" Visible='<%# Eval("NAME").ToString() == "Edit" %>' 
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

Or if you want the opposite

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/icoedit.png" 
CommandName="Edit" Visible='<%# Eval("NAME").ToString() != "Edit" %>' 
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```